# There is a similar rule to vue/padding-line-between-tags form ANGULAR, for html template?

Tags: html, angular, eslint

This not working! I would like add blank line space between tags to separate concept between elements in HTML file. I use VSCODE. I execute script `"lint:check": "ng lint"`, (ESLINT) in package.json file.

template.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-template',
  templateUrl: './template.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./template.component.scss'],
})
```

.eslintrc.json

```
{
  "files": ["*.html"],
  "extends": ["plugin:@angular-eslint/template/recommended"],
  "rules": {
    "padding-line-between-statements": [
      "error",
      [{ "blankLine": "always", "prev": "*", "next": "*" }]
    ]
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<div>
  <!-- ✓ GOOD: -->
  <div></div>
  
  <div>
  </div>
  
  <div />
  
  <div />
  <!-- ✗ BAD: -->
  <div></div>
  <div>
  </div>
  <div /><div />
</div>
```

Could you help me?

Thanks.